# Eigenvectors of $\text{diag}(x) - xx^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Given a vector $x$ what are the eigenvectors of $\text{diag}(x) - xx^T$?

My observations so far:

1. If we had only the first term, the matrix would already be diagonal.
2. The second term, on the other hand, has a diagonal form with a single nonzero entry corresponding to the direction parallel to $x$
3. This matrix acts on the vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ to yield a multiple of $x$.
4. I also see how to invert the matrix using the Woodbury identity.

Comment: What makes you think that this diagonalization is simple?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3621008/81360) is related