# Effect of rank-one update on the smallest eigenvalue and its eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, generalized-eigenvector

Suppose diagonal $D\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ with $D\succeq 0, v\in \mathbb R^n,$ and $\alpha>0$ are given. Can we $\textit{exactly}$ identify the smallest eigenvalue of $D+\alpha vv^T$ and its corresponding eigenvector (based on $v$ and given eigenpairs of $D$)?

Even though the method to identify the whole spectrum is given in [Eigenvectors of rank one update matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621008/eigenvectors-of-rank-one-update-matrix?rq=1), I am only interested in finding the smallest eigenvalue and its eigenvector. So, I wonder if something more can be said!

Comment: @user1551 thanks. It’s edited!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052997/eigenvalues-of-a-rank-one-update-of-a-matrix

Comment: thank you but since I am only looking for the smallest eigenpair, I was hoping that this could be obtained easier than the whole spectrum.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the smallest eigenvalue could be determined analytically when the others can’t, since restricting attention to the smallest doesn’t change the general character of the equation to be solved.

Comment: If you’re looking for an exact value rather than a numerical approximation, there’s not going to be a method that makes it faster to obtain one particular eigenvalue/eigenvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only simple connection that can be shown for the smallest eigenvalue of $D+\alpha vv^T$ is the following:

$$\lambda_{\min}(D+\alpha vv^T) \ge \min (d_1,\dots,d_n)=\lambda_{\min}(D).$$

This follows from the fact that the roots of the following

$$f(\lambda) = 1+\alpha \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{v_i^2}{d_i-\lambda}$$

are the eigenvalues of $D+\alpha vv^T$ (specials cases of $v_i=0$ or $d_i=d_j$ for some $i,j$ can be managed following this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3632874/1231520)). One can see that $f(\lambda)$ tends to $1$ and $+\infty$ as $\lambda \to -\infty$ and $\lambda \to \left (\min ( d_1,\dots,d_n ) \right )^-$, respectively. As $f(\lambda)$ is increasing over this interval, the smallest root of $f(\lambda)$ cannot be smaller than $\min ( d_1,\dots,d_n )$; it can be equal to if $v_i=0$ for $i$ with $d_i=\min ( d_1,\dots,d_n )$.

This could be alternatively proven using the fact that $\lambda_{\min}(X)$ is increasing in $X \in S^n$ with respect to the order $\succeq $  for **any** symmetric $D$.

In a very special case that $d_1\ne 0, d_2=\dots=d_n=0$, the eigenvalue can be obtained explicitly (which is also known from [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33614/analytic-formula-for-leading-eigenvector-of-uut-vvt) for more general form of $uu^T+vv^T$).

After finding the eigenvalue $\tilde \lambda=\lambda_{\min}(D+\alpha vv^T)$, the **eigenvector $\tilde q$ can be explicitly** obtained using the [Bunch–Nielsen–Sorensen formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Sorensen_formula) developed for this purpose as follows:

$$\tilde q_i = c\frac{v_i}{d_i - \tilde \lambda}, i=1,\dots,n $$

where $c\neq 0$ is an arbitrary number.